# How to compare datetime in SQL Server in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have `CreatedDate` as `datetime` column in my database table. I want to fetch the rows where `CreatedDate` and current time difference is more than 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from TableName where (DateDiff(hh,CreatedDate,GetDate())>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Amit Singh works if you only care about the hour value itself, versus any 60 minute period.

The problem with using DATEDIFF(hh) that way is that times of 13:01 and 14:59 are only one "hour" apart.

Like:

```
select datediff(hh,'1/1/2001 13:59','1/1/2001 14:01')
```

I think doing this would address that issue:

```
declare @cd datetime='9/12/2013 03:10';

declare @t table(id int,CreatedDate datetime);
insert @t select 1,'9/12/2013 02:50';
insert @t select 2,'9/12/2013 02:05';


select * from @t where @cd>(DateAdd(hh,1,CreatedDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dan Bellandi raises a valid point, but if it really matters if the dates should be 60 minutes apart, then just check if they are 60 minutes apart:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DateColumnName, GETDATE()) >= 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect any rows created in the future...

```
where CreatedDate < dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   CREATE TABLE trialforDate
    (
      id INT NULL,
      NAME VARCHAR(20) NULL,
      addeddate DATETIME NULL
    )
INSERT INTO trialforDate VALUES (1,'xxxx',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO trialforDate VALUES (2,'yyyy',GETDATE())
INSERT INTO trialforDate VALUES (1,'zzzz','2013-09-12 11:20:40.533')

    SELECT  *
    FROM    trialforDate
    WHERE   GETDATE() >  DATEADD(HOUR, 1, addeddate)
```

Answer (score -1):

C# Code

```
DateTime param1= System.DateTime.Now;
DateTime param2= System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CreatedDate = param1 AND CreatedDate =param2;
```